# Apache Groovy project `gradlew clean dist` fails under JDK 16.0.2 with '/SharedConfiguration...compiled by a more recent of Java...version 61.0

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle

I'm trying to build the Apache Groovy project. The Apache Groovy project recommends asking questions on Slack or StackOverflow. I haven't received the email for Slack invite, so I'm trying StackOverflow first.

Per the `README.adoc`, I'm using Java 16+. I don't see any other requirements or setup required per the README.adoc, unless I missed something. I appreciate any help.

From a clean `git clone` of the Apache Groovy project I run `./gradlew clean dist` and get the following error:

```
org/apache/groovy/gradle/SharedConfiguration has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file v
ersions up to 60.0
```

This can be reproduced as follows:

```
mkdir groovy-jdk16 && cd "$_"
java -version # initially java is not found (i.e. no conflicting versions)
export PATH="/c/java/jdk-16.0.2/bin:$PATH"
java -version
git clone https://github.com/apache/groovy.git
cd groovy/
./gradlew clean dist
```

LOG for JDK 16.0.2:

```
groovy $mkdir groovy-jdk16 && cd "$_"
groovy-jdk16 $java -version # initially java is not found (i.e. no conflicting versions)
bash: java: command not found
groovy-jdk16 $export PATH="/c/java/jdk-16.0.2/bin:$PATH"
groovy-jdk16 $java -version
openjdk version "16.0.2" 2021-07-20
  - okio-jvm-2.10.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.10.0) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
This can indicate that a dependency has been compromised. Please carefully verify the signatures and checksums.

Open this report for more details: file:///C:/projects/groovy/groovy-jdk16/groovy/build/reports/dependency-verification/at-1671383936580/dependency-verification-report.html

This build uses Gradle Build Scans to gather statistics, share information about
failures, environmental issues, dependencies resolved during the build and more.
Build scans will be published after each build, if you accept the terms of
service, and in particular the privacy policy.

Please read

    https://gradle.com/terms-of-service
    https://gradle.com/legal/privacy

and then:

  - set the `GRADLE_SCANS_ACCEPT` to `yes`/`no` if you agree with/refuse the TOS
  - or create the C:\Users\me\.gradle\gradle-scans-license-agree.txt file with `yes`/`no` in it if you agree with/refuse

And we'll not bother you again. Note that build scans are only made public if
you share the URL at the end of the build.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
org/apache/groovy/gradle/SharedConfiguration has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recog
nizes class file versions up to 60.0

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
8 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 5 from cache
groovy $
```

*TRY JDK 17.0.2*
I see a lot of references to JDK 17 "sealed" classes in the code, so tried JDK 17.0.2 which results in the following error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: precompiled_OrgApacheGroovyBadPracticesDetection`

This can be reproduced as follows:

```
mkdir groovy-jdk17 && cd "$_"
java -version # initially java is not found (i.e. no conflicting versions)
export PATH="/c/java/jdk-17.0.2/bin:$PATH"
java -version
git clone https://github.com/apache/groovy.git
cd groovy/
./gradlew clean dist
```

LOG for JDK 17.0.2:

```
groovy $mkdir groovy-jdk17 && cd "$_"
java -version
git clone https://github.com/apache/groovy.git
cd groovy/
./gradlew clean dist
groovy-jdk17 $java -version # initially java is not found (i.e. no conflicting versions)
bash: java: command not found
groovy-jdk17 $export PATH="/c/java/jdk-17.0.2/bin:$PATH"
groovy-jdk17 $java -version
openjdk version "17.0.2" 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
groovy-jdk17 $git clone https://github.com/apache/groovy.git
Cloning into 'groovy'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 401543, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (2177/2177), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (811/811), done.
remote: Total 401543 (delta 1253), reused 2063 (delta 1143), pack-reused 399366
Receiving objects: 100% (401543/401543), 203.41 MiB | 2.73 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (249207/249207), done.
Updating files: 100% (4979/4979), done.
groovy-jdk17 $cd groovy/
groovy $./gradlew clean dist
Type-safe project accessors is an incubating feature.

> Task :build-logic:compileJava FROM-CACHE
Dependency verification failed for configuration ':build-logic:compileClasspath'
One artifact failed verification: build-info-extractor-gradle-4.30.1.jar (org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.30.1) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
This can indicate that a dependency has been compromised. Please carefully verify the signatures and checksums.

Open this report for more details: file:///C:/projects/groovy/groovy-jdk17/groovy/build/reports/dependency-verification/at-1671384519313/dependency-verification-report.html

> Configure project :
Dependency verification failed for configuration ':classpath'
5 artifacts failed verification:
  - build-info-extractor-gradle-4.30.1.jar (org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.30.1) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  - moshi-1.12.0.jar (com.squareup.moshi:moshi:1.12.0) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  - moshi-kotlin-1.12.0.jar (com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:1.12.0) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  - okhttp-4.9.3.jar (com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.9.3) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  - okio-jvm-2.10.0.jar (com.squareup.okio:okio:2.10.0) from repository Gradle Central Plugin Repository
This can indicate that a dependency has been compromised. Please carefully verify the signatures and checksums.

Open this report for more details: file:///C:/projects/groovy/groovy-jdk17/groovy/build/reports/dependency-verification/at-1671384519313/dependency-verification-report.html

This build uses Gradle Build Scans to gather statistics, share information about
failures, environmental issues, dependencies resolved during the build and more.
Build scans will be published after each build, if you accept the terms of
service, and in particular the privacy policy.

Please read

    https://gradle.com/terms-of-service
    https://gradle.com/legal/privacy

and then:

  - set the `GRADLE_SCANS_ACCEPT` to `yes`/`no` if you agree with/refuse the TOS
  - or create the C:\Users\me\.gradle\gradle-scans-license-agree.txt file with `yes`/`no` in it if you agree with/refuse

And we'll not bother you again. Note that build scans are only made public if
you share the URL at the end of the build.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\projects\groovy\groovy-jdk17\groovy\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.apache.groovy-core']
> Failed to apply plugin 'org.apache.groovy-core'.
   > Failed to apply plugin 'org.apache.groovy-common'.
      > Failed to apply plugin 'org.apache.groovy-bad-practices-detection'.
         > java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: precompiled_OrgApacheGroovyBadPracticesDetection

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 6s
8 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 5 from cache
groovy $
```

Comment: It runs successfully for me and on our CI servers, e.g. as a github action:
https://github.com/apache/groovy/actions/runs/3733425821/jobs/6334203547
Do you have a JAVA_HOME environment variable pointing to JDK17 when trying to compile with JDK16? That's what the error suggests to me.

Answer (score 0):

DOH! After switching to the `GROOVY_4_0_6` tag branch, `./gradlew clean dist` completes successfully under JDK 17.0.2. The issue reported above only occurs on the `master` branch.